How to parse RUNDECK keystore keys to shell script?
I have shell script to get the data from database. in that script i want to use password. so i want convert that password to rundeck key and i want to apply in the script. I tried but i am not able to pass the password to the script. This is correct way to pass the password or there is another way to encrypt the password in rundeck.
below is my script. i passed secret key like this
#!/bin/bash
# Set Oracle environment variables
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/19/dbhome_1
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export ORACLE_SID=orcl
# Set Oracle database credentials
DB_USER="automation"
DB_PASSWORD="$RD_OPTION_AUTOMATIONPASS"
DB_SID="icici"

# Directory to store reports
REPORT_DIR="/u01/"

# Dynamically calculate dates for 'previous hour'
START_DATE=$(date --date='1 hour ago' '+%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.000000000 %p')
END_DATE=$(date '+%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.000000000 %p')

# Output file with timestamp
OUTPUT_FILE="$REPORT_DIR/hour_report_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).txt"

# SQL command with dynamic dates
SQL_COMMAND="SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF;
select * from events
WHERE EVENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('$START_DATE', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM') AND TO_TIMESTAMP('$END_DATE', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM');"

# Run SQL Command
echo "$SQL_COMMAND" | sqlplus -S "$DB_USER/$DB_PASSWORD@$DB_SID" 


in this way i store the password in keystore
I call the key from the key store

To parse Rundeck options on inline bash scripts use @option.myoption@ way. ${option.myoption} is for command steps, and $RD_OPTION_MYOPTION is for script steps.
eg, this script
DB_PASSWORD="$RD_OPTION_MYPASSWD"
echo $DB_PASSWORD

is called by this job:
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 77cef636-412e-4912-a143-eedd70e7b853
  loglevel: INFO
  name: HelloWorld
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  options:
  - name: mypasswd
    secure: true
    storagePath: keys/mypassword
    valueExposed: true
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: {}
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - fileExtension: .sh
      interpreterArgsQuoted: false
      plugins:
        LogFilter:
        - config:
            color: red
            replacement: '[SECURE]'
          type: mask-passwords
      scriptInterpreter: /bin/bash
      scriptfile: /home/user/myscript.sh
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 77cef636-412e-4912-a143-eedd70e7b853

With password mask log output (a good practice)
Without password mask log output (just for testing)
Now, you're probably running that job in a remote node. You need to configure the Rundeck option passing to SSH by following this, I'm pretty sure that is the root cause.
Regards.
